# R Markdown not knitting due to rbind error

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I'm a new RMarkdown user trying to render a .Rmd file to Word and I haven't been able to get it to spit out anything at all.  Every time that I try to knit the file, I get the following error:

```
Error in rbind(info, getNamespaceInfo(env, "S3methods")) : 
  number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)
Calls: :: ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

I started by reinstalling the "knitr" and "evaluate" packages (the latter due to an answer to a separate question) and then pared down the code to just the bare bones:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Anonymous"
output: word_document
---
Test
```

Not even this small amount of code works, with each attempt to knit things together resulting in the same error as above.

What am I missing?

Comment: "number of columns of matrices must match" Did you check that the matrices the error is referring to does have same number of columns?

Comment: Any matrices being referenced are being used internally as part of a package or function within a package.  The code I'm trying to knit is in the block above and has no references of any kind.

Comment: I also had this problem after updating to RStudio 1.2.5042 and rtools40, but RStudio was running R 3.6.3 (my R4.0.0 version accidentally got uninstalled without me knowing).

Answer (score 0):

From [this thread](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Error-in-rbind-info-getNamespaceInfo-env-quot-S3methods-quot-td4755490.html) in the R-devel mailing list, it seems one or some of your R packages are broken. Two things you can try:

1. [Upgrade R and R packages](https://yihui.name/en/2017/05/when-in-doubt-upgrade/). Run `update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)` after you have installed a newer version of R.
2. If that doesn't fix the problem, reinstall all packages: `install.packages(.packages(TRUE))` (this is not the ideal way to reinstall packages when you have multiple library paths `.libPaths()`).